# mod_rewrite to lose file extension, rewrite, and work with or without trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make my URLs pretty.

`example.com/en/directions.php`

`example.com/en/directions/`

Should both rewrite to

`example.com/en/directions`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

This currently generates a 500 error on `example.com/en/directions/` and leaves the .php with`example.com/en/directions.php`.

Bonus points if you can make me understand how rewrite conditions and rewrite rules work. Does it follow *if any of these conditions match* then *do this*. And what about the `-d` and `-f`, what are they doing?

Comment: The rewritecond folow the "must all be valid" unless you add the flag [OR] at the end of the rewritecond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check against `-f` fails because of the trailing slash so you need to do an additional check against it *without* a possible trailing slash:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/?$
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

> how rewrite conditions and rewrite rules work. Does it follow if any of these conditions match then do this. And what about the -d and -f, what are they doing?

Any number of conditions preceding a rule *only apply to that rule* and they are all required to match. If you want one condition *or* another, then you can include the `[OR]` flag at the end of the condition:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

As for the `-f` and `-d`, they are resource checks, to see if a given path points to a file or a directory. See [apache's mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for the full explanation.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I've got some reading to do. In practice the trailing slash wasn't appropriate since it broke the navigation using relative urls. So I changed the `RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1.php`. I'm not sure if I should also remove `/?` from `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*?)/?$`. It doesn't seem to make a difference either way.